# iOS UICollectionView: Cells not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm missing something obvious here as this isn't a difficult task.
I have my Collection view in storyboard (amongst other views), with the prototype cell's reuse id being "Cell", and a UILabel in that cell, with a tag of 100.
The code (boilerplate):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    label.text = @"Hello";

    return cell;
}
```

The code is within a `UICollectionViewController`, as it should.
When i run, the view appears yet no cells or text are visible.

A `NSLog` in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` confirms that it is called, 4 times.
I've even changed the prototype cell's background color which shows that not even the cell's are appearing.

In the `viewDidLoad`, it calls:     `[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];`

What am i missing?

Comment: You don't need to register anything for a collection view, if you make the cell in a storyboard . The only thing you need to do is make sure that you set the identifier in IB.

Comment: the register came with the collection view controller as boilplate code. the only thing i've edited is the return of sections, returns of number of cells, plus the UIlabel text bit.

Answer (score 5):

Use like this:
Instead of registerClass: use registerNib:

```
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self.collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionPhotoItem" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
else{
    [self.collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionPhotoItem_ipad" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are under any-any ratio in your storyboard 
if you are working with any other configuration and you tried to use the simulation it might not show up

for example  if you use regular width and compact hight and then tried to use the simulator in your Xcode all your work will not show up !