# UICollectionView is showing but the cells are not showing in swift

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a collectionView programmatically (without storyboard). I set the background color to red, and it is showing properly. But the cells are not showing. Does anyone know why the cells are not showing?

```
private let cellId = "cellId"
class InfoViewShow: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
private let cellHeight:CGFloat = 80

var collectionView: UICollectionView?
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

override init() {
    super.init()

    setupCollectionview()

    collectionView?.registerClass(InfoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

private func setupCollectionview() {
    if let view = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
        //let y = (view.frame.width * 10 / 16) + 34 + 26
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero , collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height) // y to y
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.width, cellHeight)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5); //top,left,bottom,right
}
}
```

Comment: The regular problems are that the data source and delegate are not set or the size is too small, add breakpoints to see if the cellForItem is being called. You can try to export those methods to extension, sometimes it's works

Comment: I try putting some breakpoints on both cellforitems, and numberofitems and neither of them are called. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: Try to init the collection view with size greater than zero

Comment: I did, and I am getting the same result. The cells still are not showing. collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)  The UICollectionView is showing, with a red background since I change the color to red, But not the cells. I dont think the data source nor the delegate are being called at all

Comment: I think your problem is the flow layout, set the properties of it, especially the itemSize

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial thought actually before I posted the question. The thing is, I set the properties for it, it's just not calling them. @Yitschak

Comment: Did you try to debug the view hierarchy?

Comment: http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/devda5478599 press on the "Debug view graph" button during runtime. Examine the views on the left. And the properties on the right panel. Good luck

Comment: @Yitschak I think that's were my problem is. Cause there a warning in the view hierarchy. I'm going look into it more. Thank you

Comment: If you'll succeed I'll post an answer so you'll accept it. Ok?

Comment: Did it worked??

Comment: @Yitschak no it did not. I started working on the menu for the app, while doing some research about why the delegate and data source functions are not being called at all

Comment: @Yitschak I figured how to make the cells show. I called "collectionview.layoutSubviews()" in the init function. but now I'm encountering another problem. Whenever I click on any of the cells that are showing, they all disappear. Do you have any idea why is that happening?

Comment: LayoutSubviews is not a good idea and as you can see it's not stable.. I want to debug it... Can you upload a sample?

Comment: Does your cell created in storyboard? You can try to use registerNib instead registerClass. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27837843

Comment: No, I created it programmatically. I'm going to send you a sample of my code as soon as I get home. When I don't call layoutsubviews, the cells don't show at all. When I call it, they show but only if I don't tap on them

Comment: I hope I find the problem..

Comment: I'm sorry, just started a holiday vacation without my Mac, will be back in a week

Answer (score 0):

I dont' see you add `collectionView` to view.

```
if let view = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
        //let y = (view.frame.width * 10 / 16) + 34 + 26
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero , collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height) // y to y

        ///try add
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
```

Comment: I add it inside of a helper function that I have as such             let infoView = InfoViewShow()
            barberProfileView.addSubview(infoView.collectionView!)

Comment: @ralph007  do use debug that your code run into `if let view = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow { ?`

Comment: I have actually. that's how I got access to the keyWindow. i feel like the delegate methods are not being called at all. cause I put some print statements inside of each of them for debugging purposes, and they are not being printed, nor called when I put breakpoints on them

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` of `UICollectionViewDataSource` delegate method. 
This method is optional but you must implement it and return at least one section.

Comment: I just tried that and it's not working still. I put breakpoints on the delegate functions, and I realized that are not being called at all

Comment: Try 'self.collectionView.reloadData()' in viewDidLoad method

Comment: It did not fix the problem. the collectionview is showing, with a red background since i set the background color to red so I can see it better, but not the cells. I dont think the datasource nor the delegate funcs are bing called at all

Answer (score 0):

I know I am 6 years late to answer this question but I also struggled with it for 2 days before finding the mistake I was making. Hope this answer helps someone.

Check whether you have written the following two lines in your override func viewDidLoad()

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```